# Retranslate TLS encrypted packets on Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a question if there are some ready modules for my task. I need to send from client (browser) to server TLS encrypted message that will proceed it sending to the destination point (any website). So in this task i have 3 parts: client, node-server, destination. I control only the client and node so the other side is not my. How it is called? TLS tunnel? Maybe, but i didn't find any that will achieve the described. So at the end node-server operates with encrypted messages and it does not able to read them. Looking on raw-socket, but it seems very ugly solution...

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: It's called proxy-server

Comment: Why do you need it? Is your website in a closed system? Otherwise The "example.com" could simple connect to your client site and have the same "data". I just want to understand what is the reason behind it.

Comment: Website operates with private REST api that i need to hide from browser debuggers. It wouldn't protect it 100%, but will make it harder because web-socket aren't showing in browser debuggers.

Comment: @Shpingalet007 You cannot hide an API. Also this has nothing to do with TLS vs TCP?!

Comment: He is right, there is a thing called websocket over TLS, but I am not sure how you can proxy a websocket connection. And of course he means TCP as HTTPS (I assume). My other question is that why do you send data to the client if you don't want the client to see it? You got personal data all over the internet using REST API. What kind of attack do you want to prevent?